# SQL find products sold in business days

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find number of products sold in +/- 5 business  days from a particular date. I have a utlitiy function which tells whether the date is business day or non business day but I'm unable to figure out how do I use that in my query to determine +/5 - business days from a fixed date.

This is my query

```
Declare @MarketDate datetime= '2022-05-01'
select * from products
where Saledate between @MarketDate-5 and @MarketDate+5
```

I have a utlity to find business days between two dates but not sure how to use that within my query [udfUtility_DateRange](@DATE_FROM, @DATE_TO) - this gives me the business days between two dates

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: And did your business days container Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: I'm using Ms SQL Server, business day excludes  weekends and public holidays.

Comment: `excludes weekends and public holidays.` I think you might need to make a calendar table because the different country has their own  different  `public holidays`

Comment: I have a utlity to find business days between two dates but not sure how to use that within my query. 

[udfUtility_DateRange](@DATE_FROM, @DATE_TO) - this gives me the business days between two dates.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need? It is based on mysql. You can +/- the date relative to the current one.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE saledate >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -5 DAY) AND saledate <= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL +5 DAY)
```

Comment: MSSQL -> SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -10, '2021-07-12') AS [10 day Before] 
     , DATEADD(DAY, 10, '2021-07-12')  AS [10 day After]